# Query firebase in each cycle of a map array in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, array.prototype.map

I have an array, I go through it with a map, and so I render some componentes

```
const list = [{'id':1,'name':'a'},{'id':2,'name':'b'},{'id':3,'name':'c'}]

list.map(item=>{
  return <Item key={item.id}/>
})
```

This works perfect for me. But now I need to make a query to firebase in each cicle of map and send the result of that query to each  as props, but i only get empty arrays.

```
list.map(item=>{
    let firebasedata=[]
    var ref = database.ref('example');

   //query to firebase for each item in the "list", and save the array result of each item in "firebasedata"

    ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(item.id).on('value', snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(x=> {
          firebasedata.push(x.val())
        }); 
        console.log(firebasedata) //here I have the result of each query for each map item 
    });

  console.log(firebasedata) //here I get only empty arrays, and when returning the Item, the prop also goes with an empty array

  return <Item key={item.id}  firebasedata={firebasedata}/>  //firebasedata empty array for each Item
})
```

How can I make the query within the map for each item of the list, and send each array through props in the return of  component?

Comment: I would take the firebase request outside of map iteration, create a handler function for that, then pass the handler function to the Item component as props with the id parameter. Then whatever that function returns, handle that inside the component's file.